# sum with sql and direct condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to show the value only when the sum is higher than 2

Strange output

```
 select 1+3 > 2;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 register)
```

---

```
ERROR:  column "val" does not exist
line 1: select 1+3 as val where val > 2;
                                 ^
```

---

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CASE"
line 1: select 1+3 as val CASE val > 2;
                          ^
```

What is the correct way? None of these seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use derived column in `where` clause, there're many discussions on SO about this. One way to do this is to use subquery or CTE

```
select val
from (select 1+3 as val) as v
where val > 2
```

or

```
with cte (
    select 1+3 as val
)
select val
from cte
where val > 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a subselect, because the columns defined in the select clause aren't available for use in where clauses:

```
select val
from (select 1+3 as val) as vals
where val > 2
```

A CTE also works:

```
with vals as (
select 1+3 as val
)
select val
from vals
where val > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out *HAVING* function. See details here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: `having` does a very, very different thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write,

<s>select sum(1+3) as val having sum(1+3)>2</s>

As @Denis Suggested,

```
select val from (select 1+3 as val) as v where val > 2
```

Comment: @Denis I can't understand. it will produce any wrong answer apart from the user asked output?

Comment: @DownVoter Can you please explain what's wrong with my query?

Comment: in this case yes, it works, but in the general case it won't. The `having` clause allows to filter a grouped statement — that is, after a `group by` clause. And normally after an aggregate function has been applied, such as what you did. It should *not* be used as a `where` substitute, unless you crave to get terrible query plans — and oftentimes completely erroneous results due to the grouping. Run explain analyze with your query vs those that Roman and I suggested, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Denis Thanks for giving explanation regarding aggregate function. I edited my answer according to your suggestion